# Remove dates which are not continuous in the data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe and I want to filter out the entries that are not continuous in date. In other words, I am looking at the cluster of continuous dates.

```
a %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% mutate(day_dif = day - lag(day))
```

Source: local data frame [20 x 3]

```
          day count day_dif
       (date) (int)  (dfft)
1  2016-02-02    12 NA days
2  2016-02-03    80  1 days
3  2016-02-04   102  1 days
4  2016-02-05    97  1 days
5  2016-02-06   118  1 days
6  2016-02-07   115  1 days
7  2016-02-08     4  1 days
8  2016-02-20    13 12 days
9  2016-02-21   136  1 days
10 2016-02-22   114  1 days
11 2016-02-23   134  1 days
12 2016-02-24   126  1 days
13 2016-02-25   128  1 days
14 2016-02-26    63  1 days
15 2016-02-27   118  1 days
16 2016-03-06     1  8 days
17 2016-03-29    28 23 days
18 2016-04-03    18  5 days
19 2016-04-08    18  5 days
20 2016-04-27    23 19 days
```

In this, I want to filter out entries that are not continuous in date. For ex, 2016-03-06,  2016-03-29, 2016-04-03 are single day entries which needs to be removed. I am looking only for continuous days entries. entries that occur with multiple days. My ideal output which I am looking is,

```
          day count day_dif  Cluster
       (date) (int)  (dfft)
1  2016-02-02    12 NA days     1
2  2016-02-03    80  1 days     1
3  2016-02-04   102  1 days     1
4  2016-02-05    97  1 days     1
5  2016-02-06   118  1 days     1
6  2016-02-07   115  1 days     1 
7  2016-02-08     4  1 days     1
8  2016-02-20    13 12 days     2
9  2016-02-21   136  1 days     2
10 2016-02-22   114  1 days     2
11 2016-02-23   134  1 days     2
12 2016-02-24   126  1 days     2
13 2016-02-25   128  1 days     2
14 2016-02-26    63  1 days     2
15 2016-02-27   118  1 days     2
```

Where cluster column indicates the date clusters and also the output removes the single dates. Here 1 in the cluster column indicates, first group of dates and 2 indicates second group of dates. `If there are more than 3 continuous days, I want to consider as on cluster`.

I am trying to do this by using lag functions and all. But without much success. Can anybody help me in doing this? Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way to deal with the first `NA` values. Here, I manually assigned it to 0. Then, because the difference of continuous date will be 1, you can take advantage of this property to create a boolean vector and then use `cumsum` to get the results. Finally, you can remove those groups which their length are equal to 1.

```
# Let the first NA equal to 0
df[which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)] <- 0

df %>% mutate(cluster=cumsum(day_dif !=1)) %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>% filter(length(cluster) > 1) %>% ungroup()

# Source: local data frame [15 x 4]

#          day count day_dif cluster
#        (date) (int)  (dfft)   (int)
# 1  2016-02-02    12  0 days       1
# 2  2016-02-03    80  1 days       1
# 3  2016-02-04   102  1 days       1
# 4  2016-02-05    97  1 days       1
# 5  2016-02-06   118  1 days       1
# 6  2016-02-07   115  1 days       1
# 7  2016-02-08     4  1 days       1
# 8  2016-02-20    13 12 days       2
# 9  2016-02-21   136  1 days       2
# 10 2016-02-22   114  1 days       2
# 11 2016-02-23   134  1 days       2
# 12 2016-02-24   126  1 days       2
# 13 2016-02-25   128  1 days       2
# 14 2016-02-26    63  1 days       2
# 15 2016-02-27   118  1 days       2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rle` to subset the rows

```
i1 <- c(TRUE, a1$day_dif[-1] >=3)
i2 <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(i1), {values1 <- values
           values[values1 &lengths >3] <- FALSE
           values[!values1]<- TRUE}))
a1$Cluster <- cumsum(i1)
a1[i2,]
#          day count day_dif Cluster
#1  2016-02-02    12 NA days       1
#2  2016-02-03    80  1 days       1
#3  2016-02-04   102  1 days       1
#4  2016-02-05    97  1 days       1
#5  2016-02-06   118  1 days       1
#6  2016-02-07   115  1 days       1
#7  2016-02-08     4  1 days       1
#8  2016-02-20    13 12 days       2
#9  2016-02-21   136  1 days       2
#10 2016-02-22   114  1 days       2
#11 2016-02-23   134  1 days       2
#12 2016-02-24   126  1 days       2
#13 2016-02-25   128  1 days       2
#14 2016-02-26    63  1 days       2
#15 2016-02-27   118  1 days       2
```

---

The above code can be also be chained (`%>%`)

```
a1 %>%
   mutate(i1 = c(TRUE, day_dif[-1] >=3))  %>%
   do(data.frame(., i2 = inverse.rle(within.list(rle(.$i1), {
                     values1 <- values
                     values[values1 & lengths >3] <- FALSE
                     values[!values1] <- TRUE
                      })))) %>%
   mutate(Cluster = cumsum(i1)) %>%
   filter(i2) %>% 
   select(-i1, -i2)
#          day count day_dif Cluster
#1  2016-02-02    12 NA days       1
#2  2016-02-03    80  1 days       1
#3  2016-02-04   102  1 days       1
#4  2016-02-05    97  1 days       1
#5  2016-02-06   118  1 days       1
#6  2016-02-07   115  1 days       1
#7  2016-02-08     4  1 days       1
#8  2016-02-20    13 12 days       2
#9  2016-02-21   136  1 days       2
#10 2016-02-22   114  1 days       2
#11 2016-02-23   134  1 days       2
#12 2016-02-24   126  1 days       2
#13 2016-02-25   128  1 days       2
#14 2016-02-26    63  1 days       2
#15 2016-02-27   118  1 days       2
```

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(day = structure(c(16833, 16834, 16835, 16836, 
16837, 16838, 16839, 16851, 16852, 16853, 16854, 16855, 16856, 
16857, 16858, 16866, 16889, 16894, 16899, 16918), class = "Date"), 
count = c(12L, 80L, 102L, 97L, 118L, 115L, 4L, 13L, 136L, 
114L, 134L, 126L, 128L, 63L, 118L, 1L, 28L, 18L, 18L, 23L
)), .Names = c("day", "count"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "data.frame")

a1 <- a %>%
        mutate(day_dif = day - lag(day))
```